# Do BTRS errors always mean a drive is dying?

Tags: fedora, btrfs, corruption

I believe my drive might be dying but I'm getting contradictory feedback. The drive is a *XPG Gammix AGAMMIXS11P-1TT-C S11 Pro 3D NAND PCIe NVMe Gen3x4 M.2 2280 SSD 1To*. I'm using Fedora (34 at first, then I moved on to 35 while trying to solve the problem.)

So for a couple of week I've been getting `Input/output error`'s when hashing fairly large (5+GB)  backup files. `dmesg` gives me entries like these :

```
BTRFS warning (device dm-0): csum failed root 256 ino 31359 off 70897819648 csum 0xc39e6daf expected csum 0xdd85c8f2 mirror 1
[ 4851.163157] BTRFS error (device dm-0): bdev /dev/mapper/luks-197f7c13-2430-4e53-bc76-2eb5a06a2419 errs: wr 0, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 1, gen 0
```

That's concerning in itself, and I've basically been using this computer like a read-only device, but on top of that I eventually got more btrfs errors on some random files (small config or lib files in `/usr/lib/`) and Firefox stopped working. The rest of the system was OK. I got pretty concerned so I used `nvme-cli` to get a smart log from the drive. The result seemed (and still looks) alright :

```
Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning            : 0
temperature                 : 43 C
available_spare             : 100%
available_spare_threshold   : 10%
percentage_used             : 0%
endurance group critical warning summary: 0
data_units_read             : 23,088,142
data_units_written          : 15,395,166
host_read_commands          : 87,911,793
host_write_commands         : 133,959,725
controller_busy_time        : 2,823
power_cycles                : 875
power_on_hours              : 3,634
unsafe_shutdowns            : 84
media_errors                : 0
num_err_log_entries         : 0
Warning Temperature Time    : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time : 0
Temperature Sensor 2        : 43 C
Temperature Sensor 3        : 59 C
Temperature Sensor 4        : 43 C
Temperature Sensor 5        : 43 C
Temperature Sensor 6        : 42 C
Thermal Management T1 Trans Count   : 44
Thermal Management T2 Trans Count   : 14
Thermal Management T1 Total Time    : 899
Thermal Management T2 Total Time    : 333
```

I decided to do a fresh install of Fedora 35 and the installation process worked fine. The system has been stable. Just now I decided to write my backups (~180GB) back to the drive and try hashing them, and I got a `Input/output error` again. I ran a `btrfs scrub start /` but the test came back OK :

```
UUID:             fd4449cc-ab1b-401c-8c62-916bd5e2353c
Scrub started:    Sun Jan  9 19:31:55 2022
Status:           finished
Duration:         0:00:57
Total to scrub:   182.23GiB
Rate:             3.20GiB/s
Error summary:    no errors found
```

And now the hashes works! (No `Input/output error` and the hashes show the files aren't corrupted.)

What's going on? Is my drive dying a slow death? Are there more tests (apart from `btrfs scrub` and `nvme smart-log`) I could run to find out?

---

EDIT :
I just got these with `dmesg -w` :

```
[ 1654.979314] nvme nvme0: I/O 530 QID 12 timeout, aborting
[ 1654.979326] nvme nvme0: I/O 531 QID 12 timeout, aborting
[ 1654.979330] nvme nvme0: I/O 532 QID 12 timeout, aborting
[ 1654.979334] nvme nvme0: I/O 533 QID 12 timeout, aborting
[ 1654.979337] nvme nvme0: I/O 534 QID 12 timeout, aborting
[ 1671.274745] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
[ 1671.274767] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
[ 1671.274771] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
[ 1671.274774] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
[ 1671.274776] nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x0
```

The `smartctl -a` output :

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       XPG GAMMIX S11 Pro
Serial Number:                      xxxxxxxxxxxx
Firmware Version:                   32A0T2IA
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x1cc1
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x000000
Controller ID:                      1
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          1,024,209,543,168 [1.02 TB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            204,128,706,560 [204 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Local Time is:                      Mon Jan 10 12:35:38 2022 EST
Firmware Updates (0x14):            2 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x0b):         S/H_per_NS Cmd_Eff_Lg Telmtry_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         64 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     75 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     80 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     9.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.60W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     3.80W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0450W       -        -    3  3  3  3     2000    2000
 4 -   0.0040W       -        -    4  4  4  4    15000   15000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        41 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    23,571,578 [12.0 TB]
Data Units Written:                 15,420,722 [7.89 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 89,012,266
Host Write Commands:                134,091,234
Controller Busy Time:               2,832
Power Cycles:                       878
Power On Hours:                     3,639
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   84
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 2:               41 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 3:               56 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 4:               41 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 5:               41 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 6:               40 Celsius
Thermal Temp. 1 Transition Count:   44
Thermal Temp. 2 Transition Count:   14
Thermal Temp. 1 Total Time:         899
Thermal Temp. 2 Total Time:         333

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 256 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

Self-tests results (I ran the quick test twice while working out how to use the tool) :

```
Device Self Test Log for NVME device:nvme0
Current operation  : 0
Current Completion : 0%
Self Test Result[0]:
  Operation Result             : 0
  Self Test Code               : 2
  Valid Diagnostic Information : 0
  Power on hours (POH)         : 0xe3c
  Vendor Specific              : 0 0
Self Test Result[1]:
  Operation Result             : 0
  Self Test Code               : 1
  Valid Diagnostic Information : 0
  Power on hours (POH)         : 0xe3c
  Vendor Specific              : 0 0
Self Test Result[2]:
  Operation Result             : 0
  Self Test Code               : 1
  Valid Diagnostic Information : 0
  Power on hours (POH)         : 0xe3c
  Vendor Specific              : 0 0
Self Test Result[3]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[4]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[5]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[6]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[7]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[8]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[9]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[10]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[11]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[12]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[13]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[14]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[15]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[16]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[17]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[18]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
Self Test Result[19]:
  Operation Result             : 0xf
```

If I run `dmesg | grep -i nvme` after a reboot, I get nothing concerning :

```
[    1.381334] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:01:00.0
[    1.392743] nvme nvme0: 15/0/0 default/read/poll queues
[    1.394601]  nvme0n1: p1 p2 p3
[   19.943676] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
```

Comment: check `dmesg` for IO errors and would be nice to see `smartctl -a /dev/device` output

Comment: I would not immediately deduce from whatever BTRFS failure that my drive is dying. After all, everything appears starting from a rather innocent checksum failure. Could be a DRAM error too. Do you get the possibilty to install whatever more robust filesystem and work with it ?. And BTW +1 for @ArtemS.Tashkinov suggestion.

Comment: `nvme nvme0: I/O 534 QID 12 timeout, aborting` - this is not good. Could be an issue with power saving. Check https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214755 Also check this how to run SMART self tests on your NVMe: https://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli/issues/1252

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in 2022 this question remained unanswered for a while and I forgot about it, but later on I actually did end up finding out what was wrong with the "drive". So, for the sake of people who might stumble on this question :

The drive was fine, but one of the system's ***RAM sticks*** was faulty. After some memtest86 testing proving this, I got a warranty replacement for it and never got another checksum failure or any problems with the drive or BTRFS.

---

Bit more details : I had 2 sticks of 16 GB RAM on that build, which was quite overkill for the workloads it saw. Since the faulty stick was the second one, it seldom got used by the system. This explains why the system as a whole was stable.

I would get errors on almost all large file hashes, but also intermittently on smaller files operations (a corrupted file here and there). I suppose this happened because most small file operations used the first stick of RAM and were only rarely "pushed" to the second stick by other applications using up the first 16 GB of RAM. Large file hashes were the most obvious sign of the problem because they were one of the few use cases on the system where more than 16 GB of RAM was actually useful. A professional video editor, for example, might have disavowed this system much faster than I did (they use software that handle large files very often).